# ¿How to pass an in memory access token to a server component? - nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, oauth-2.0, access-token, react-server-components

I have a refresh token in a cookie, and also an access token in memory.

So, in this client component, i'm gettin the access token, and saving it to a zustand store

```
"use client";

import Image from "next/image";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import { useStore } from "@/globalState";
import { ServerResponse, userApi } from "@/types/serverResponse";
import { useGetAccessToken } from "@/customHooks/useGetAccessToken";

const UserAccess = () => {
  const updateAccessToken = useStore((state) => state.updateAccessToken);

  const router = useRouter();

  const onSuccess = (resp: AxiosResponse<ServerResponse, any>) => {
    // console.log('access token api response');
    // console.log(resp);
    updateAccessToken(resp.data.data);
    router.push("/");
  };

  const onError = (error: unknown) => {
    console.log("access token api call failed");
    console.log(error);
  };

  const { mutate } = useGetAccessToken({
    onSuccess,
    onError,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    mutate();
  }, []);

  return (
    <motion.div>
......
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default UserAccess;
```

Then, i want to be able to access some data that only logged in users can access, for that, i need the refresh token (which is already sent in every request, because it's a cookie), but i can't pass it as props or call zustand store to get it in a **server component.**

This is how the server component looks like

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

import NavbarContainer from "@/components/molecules/home/NavbarContainer";
import { ServerResponse, userApi } from "@/types/serverResponse";

const fetchUser = async (): Promise<ServerResponse | boolean> => {
  const refreshToken = cookies().get("refresh-token");

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return false;
  }

  const resp = await userApi.get<ServerResponse>("/user/me", {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers : {
        Authorization: // i need the access token in memory );
    }
  });

  // not authorized
  if (resp.status === 401) {
  }

  return false;
};

const Navbar = async () => {
  const user = await fetchUser();

  console.log(user);

  return <NavbarContainer />;
};

export default Navbar;
```

Now, i've tried to set global headers to axios, but, it only works client side, on the server, it does not appear. Also, if i try to get the access token every time a user makes a request, that's going to be a LOT of request, and i can't put the access token in a cookie, because it would be vulnerable.

So, i really don't know how can i use my access token to fetch data on server components, what changes should i consider to be able to do this.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Refresh tokens really don't belong in cookies. It's a big red flag. The whole point of a refresh token is to send it across network boundaries once. Keep it on the server, or keep it on the client. Only send it to the oauth2 server once you're ready to actually do the refresh operation.

Comment: But that does not answer my question...

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Would you give me a link to a document/post where the information that you shared in your comment is backed, so i can see how to improve my authentication/authorization system